# Match documents where the field 1 is more than field 2

Tags: elasticsearch

```
doc1 = {
    "field1": 34,
    "field2": 15
}
doc2 = {
    "field1": 12,
    "field2": 46
}
```

How to match all the documents where field 1 is greater that field 2. 
That is in the above case the search will result in the matching of doc1 only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-script-filter.html) that can directly compare the fields.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.field1.value > doc.field2.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in order for this to work you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).